What kind of useless Stack Exchange Site is this?
Dear Puzzling Community,
what is wrong with you people? Why are you always asking such weird question? (click to see all)

Score;Title;Tag7;Society following anglo-french market activities;c-c4;Tie up a group of hounds;wp8;Photographers ridicule queen seconds before sabbath;wp8;Central Indiana rioter misbehaving;e-p4;Seaweed picked up from shelf;c-w6;Cops tailed yankee in course of action;c-c5;Violently drag european guard;c-w2;Next to the black unknown;e-p4;Uncapped velocity brought about the rich;wp5;Control dust without electric displacement;c-c7;Explicit illustration;e-p11;Brilliant information: Man after Lithium;e-p3;Judge lying about villain;c-w6;Believe in lawless gunfire killing knight;wp6;Regularly afforded deer as proviant;c-w3;Unfinished opera gets support;c-c
Fine, I'll do it. It seems like you really want everyone to visit [redacted].stackexchange.com

Do you even remember which [redacted] site you so desperately want everyone to visit?!?!

(With a hat-tip to some helpful comments below) The site you are looking for is...

 GERMAN.stackexchange.com!

First note that the 16 question titles in this enigmatic-puzzle are actually...

 cryptic-clues, as might be seen in a typical cryptic crossword (see the cryptic-crosswords tag for more examples). These can be split into a definition part (emphasised in bold in the write-up below) and a wordplay part, consisting of components needed to manufacture an answer specified by the definition. The vote count is their enumeration (i.e. the length of the answer in letters).

 We can solve the cryptic clues as follows (answers in bold and ALL CAPS):

 [c-c] Society following anglo-french market activities (7) AFFAIRS = AF (anglo-french) + FAIR (market) + S (Society)

 [wp] Tie up | a group of hounds (4) PACK = ddef

 [wp] Photographers ridicule queen seconds before sabbath (8) SHOOTERS = S (seconds) + HOOT (ridicule) + ER (queen) + S (sabbath)

 [e-p] Central Indiana rioter misbehaving (8) INTERIOR = IN (Indiana) + RIOTER*

 [c-w] Seaweed picked up from shelf (4) RACK = “wrack”

 [c-c] Cops tailed yankee in course of action (6) POLICY = POLIC(-e) + Y (yankee)

 [c-w] Violently drag european guard (5) GARDE = DRAG* + E (european)

 [e-p] Next to the black unknown (2) BY = B (black) + Y (unknown)

 [wp] Uncapped velocity brought about the rich (4) DEEP = (-s)PEED<

 [c-c] Control dust without electric displacement (5) POWER = POW(-d)ER

 [e-p] Explicit | illustration (7) GRAPHIC = ddef

 [e-p] Brilliant information: Man after Lithium (11) INTELLIGENT = INTEL (information) + LI (Lithium) + GENT (Man)

 [c-w] Judge lying about villain (3) DOG = GOD< (Thanks to @noneuclideanisms in comments)

 [wp] Believe in lawless gunfire killing knight (6) FIGURE = GU(-n)FIRE*

 [c-w] Regularly afforded deer as proviant (6) FODDER = _F_O_D_D _E_R

 [c-c] Unfinished opera gets support (3) AID = AID(-a)

Then note the significance of the number of clues and the strangely abbreviated tags...

 There are sixteen clues, split by tag into four groups of four - we have ourselves a connect-wall puzzle! We can surmise this elsehow also... Note that if we pinpoint the tags that have been censored (by comparing the initials with those on the Tags page here on Puzzling), these equate to:

 [c-c] = cryptic-clues
 [c-w] = connect-wall
 [e-p] = enigmatic-puzzle
 [wp] = wordplay

 We recognise three of these as tags we are already having to use, so the last remaining one - connect-wall - likely needs to be used too. So let's resolve the wall using standard connecting wall rules, by categorising its 16 terms into 4 connected groups of 4...

 Group 1 (c-c): Can be preceded by FOREIGN:
 Foreign AFFAIRS, Foreign AID, Foreign POLICY, Foreign POWER

 Group 2 (c-w): Have some connection to MANGER (thanks to @Tobbs in comments):
 "DOG in the manger", FODDER is placed in a manger, GARDE manger, RACK (what a manger is)

 Group 3 (e-p): Can be followed by DESIGN:
 BY design, GRAPHIC design, INTERIOR design, INTELLIGENT design

 Group 4 (wp): Connected to SIX:
 DEEP-six, Six-FIGURE, Six PACK, Six-SHOOTERS

What do we do with this? (Answer with help from @noneuclideanisms and @GentlePurpleRain in comments)

 With the words ordered as per the groups above (alphabetically by tag), this spells out an additional cryptic clue:

FOREIGN MANGER DESIGN (6)

 Here, the definition is 'Foreign', while 'design' is an anagram indicator suggesting that we need to rearrange the letters of the word 'MANGER' to find a word meaning 'Foreign'. A suitable answer to an English speaker is GERMAN, and the site german.stackexchange.com does actually exist, justifying it as the solution.

 (The fact that the OP's bio places them in Austria - a German-speaking country - is of further personal relevance!)

All of this suggests to me that for the narrator something on the Puzzling homepage is lost in translation! ;-)

I had an alternative theory for a while that the final answer should be rot13(GUVAXVAT) but I just couldn't quite make it all work out. This solution was the next to present itself as a possibility but I won't be offended if it turns out I'm not entirely correct.

Ah, that fills in some blanks and fixes some errors in my draft. I can imagine that the last step involves the [wp] tag, so that all tags get used. For example ("sbervta fvk" pbhyq zrna frvf/frggr/frk be whfg fvk*).

@MOehm Yeah, (I realise I haven't explicitly spelled out what those censored tags are) that's a possibility. I'm positive that pinning down that missing one (and understanding the 'judge') will prove crucial to knowing when I've actually got the final answer!

i was thinking the final extraction might be rot13(n pelcgvp pyhr jvgu rahzrengvba fvk, cbffvoyl jvgu "sbervta" nf na nantevaq?)

@noneuclideanisms I really like that. It probably targets the currently-missing word in that case, since the other one currently in the mix doesn't lend itself to too many that seem relevant...

the last clue might be rot13(TBQ onpxjneqf sbe QBT (be gur bgure jnl nebhaq))

There are currently two unintended answers here (CON & GRADE). The actual answer of the guard clue is a bit dodgy...

@LukasRotter 'GRADE' was actually a last minute change for me, having had 'GARDE' throughout. However, I was having trouble connecting it to anything that fitted with the rest.

Bearing all this in mind, the missing link may be "THA - THA sbqqre, THA qbt (jvgu gur pbzzrag nobir), THA enpx, naq fbzrguvat va cynpr bs 'thneq' lrg gb or qrgrezvarq"

Urm, ahh, hmm, wha? Just to help out those as lost as I.

I will confirm that the 4 words of c-w are rot13(QBT, SBQQRE, TNEQR, ENPX). The c-w connection isn't standard: While it all connects to a single word, it doesn't use the same method for each term (e.g. phrase containing X)

I think the group two words are connected with rot13(SNEZ), purely thematically. And it forms a new word following the same rule the other words do!

The c-w connection might be rot13(znatre)

@Tobbs, and maybe, it is intended to be another crytic clue: rot13(Sbervta znatre qrfvta (fvk) jurer "sbervta" vf gur qrsvavgvba naq gur fbyhgvba vf "Trezna" (nantenz bs "znatre")?  Ohg "Trezna" vf bayl sbervta vs lbh qba'g unccra gb or sebz Treznal, fb vg'f n yvggyr jrnx.)

Where Lukas is from, that's as foreign as it gets ...

Ooh, I think these last couple of observations are likely the way this should go. Plus it's a real site in the network. I'm going to make the edit because I think it all pulls together nicely. Thanks for these contributions!
